# Invalid method declaration; return type required line 10 + 14 additional errors when fixed

Tags: java

G'day I'm a bit of a newbie and I've been struggling to find why this exercise doesn't seem to compile. Any and all advice would be greatly appreciated!

Currently, the error is

> "java:10: error: invalid method declaration; return type required public setRadius (double r){"

however, when I change `public setRadius` to `public double setRadius` I get 14 errors. Here are some of them

CarApp.java:59: error: cannot find symbol

```
            System.out.println("Radius for Car 2 = " + radus2);
                                                      ^
```

CarApp.java:63: error: cannot find symbol

```
        System.out.println("Radius for Car 3 = " + radius3);
                                                      ^
```

CarApp.java:65: error: cannot find symbol

```
        car1.car(22.0);
               ^
```

CarApp.java:67: error: variable cir is already defined in method main(String[])

```
        double cir = circle1.calCircumference(); 
               ^
```

CarApp.java:68: error: variable area is already defined in method main(String[])

```
        double area = car1.calArea();
               ^
```

CarApp.java:70: error: cannot find symbol

```
class Car {
    private static double r;
    public static void Car(double rd) {
        r = rd;
    }
    public Car(Car Source){
        this.r = Source.r;
    }

public setRadius (double r){
    radius=r;
}

public double getRadius(){ 
    return this.r;
}

public double calCircumference(){
        return 2 * Math.PI * r;
}

public static double calArea() {  
        return Math.PI * r * r;
    }
}

class CarApp {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Car car1 = new Car();
        Car car2 = new Car(car1);
        Car car3 = new Car(car2);

        double rd = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
        System.out.println( "Car radius = " + rd );

        car1.car(rd);
        double cir = circle1.calCircumference(); 
        double area = circle1.calArea();

        car2.car(rd);
        double cir2 = circle2.calCircumference(); 
        double area2 = circle2.calArea();
        double radius2 = circle2.getRadius();


        car3.car(rd);
        double cir3 = circle3.calCircumference(); 
        double area3 = circle3.calArea();
        double radius3 = circle3.getRadius();

        System.out.println("Before");
        System.out.println("Circumference for Car 1 = " + cir);
        System.out.println("Area for Car 1 = " + area);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Circumference for Car 2 = " + cir2);
        System.out.println("Area for Car 2 = " + area2);
        System.out.println("Radius for Car 2 = " + radius2);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Circumference for Car 3 = " + cir3);
        System.out.println("Area for Car 3 = " + area3 );
        System.out.println("Radius for Car 3 = " + radius3);

        car1.car(22.0);
        double radius1 = car1.getRadius();      
        double cir = car1.calCircumference(); 
        double area = car1.calArea();

        car2.car(rd);
        double cir21 = car2.calCircumference(); 
        double area21 = car2.calArea();
        double radius21=car2.getRadius();

        car3.setRadius(10.0);
        double cir31 = car2.calCircumference(); 
        double area31 = car2.calArea();
        double radius31 = car2.getRadius();     

        System.out.println("After");
        System.out.println("Radius for Car 1 = " + radius1);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Circumference for Car 2 = " + cir21);
        System.out.println("Area for Car 2 = " + area21);
        System.out.println("Radius for Car 2 = " + radius21);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Radius for Car 3 = " + radius31);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing the `void` return type.

Comment: `radius` != `raduis` typo? 

System.out.println("Radius for Car 3 = " + rad**ui**s31);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code is having a lot of errors, try to fixed them by what I think you meant to do...

```
class Car {
    private static double r;

    public Car() {
        r = 0.0;
    }

    public Car(double rd) {
        r = rd;
    }

    public Car(Car Source){
        this.r = Source.getRadius();
    }

    public void setRadius (double r){
        this.r=r;
    }

    public double getRadius(){
        return this.r;
    }

    public double calCircumference(){
        return 2 * Math.PI * r;
    }

    public static double calArea() {
        return Math.PI * r * r;
    }
}

class CarApp {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Car car1 = new Car();
        Car car2 = new Car(car1);
        Car car3 = new Car(car2);

        double rd = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
        System.out.println( "Car radius = " + rd );

        car1.setRadius(rd);
        // need define circle1 like `Circle circle1 = new Circle(...)`
        double cir = circle1.calCircumference();
        double area = circle1.calArea();

        car2.setRadius(rd);

        // need to define circle2, like the above
        double cir2 = circle2.calCircumference();
        double area2 = circle2.calArea();
        double radius2 = circle2.getRadius();


        car3.setRadius(rd);
        // need to define circle3, like the above above
        double cir3 = circle3.calCircumference();
        double area3 = circle3.calArea();
        double radius3 = circle3.getRadius();

        System.out.println("Before");
        System.out.println("Circumference for Car 1 = " + cir);
        System.out.println("Area for Car 1 = " + area);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Circumference for Car 2 = " + cir2);
        System.out.println("Area for Car 2 = " + area2);
        System.out.println("Radius for Car 2 = " + raduis2);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Circumference for Car 3 = " + cir3);
        System.out.println("Area for Car 3 = " + area3 );
        System.out.println("Radius for Car 3 = " + raduis3);

        car1.setRadius(22.0);
        double radius1 = car1.getRadius();
        cir = car1.calCircumference();
        area = car1.calArea();

        car2.setRadius(rd);
        double cir21 = car2.calCircumference();
        double area21 = car2.calArea();
        double radius21=car2.getRadius();

        car3.setRadius(10.0);
        double cir31 = car2.calCircumference();
        double area31 = car2.calArea();
        double radius31 = car2.getRadius();

        System.out.println("After");
        System.out.println("Radius for Car 1 = " + raduis1);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Circumference for Car 2 = " + cir21);
        System.out.println("Area for Car 2 = " + area21);
        System.out.println("Radius for Car 2 = " + raduis21);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Radius for Car 3 = " + raduis31);
    }
}
```

hope it helps...